# How to align two pie-charts inside (or) outside a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, charts

In a report that it will be printed in (white/black) colours, I would like to add two pie charts to show a sample size that has been used in two experiments. 
I do not know how to align them, and it is quite difficult for me to use (baseline), so I thought to do it in , then I added a table just to add a caption. 
The problem is that these charts did not align very professionally. As you can see in the following Table,

[image: The output Table]

Where the code that I used to generate this, is as follows:

```
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\slice}[4]{
\pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
\let\midangle\pgfmathresult

 % slice
 \draw[thick,fill=black!10] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;

 % outer label
 \node[label=\midangle:#4] at (\midangle:1) {};

 % inner label
 \pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
 \let\temp\pgfmathresult
 \pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}
 \let\innerpos\pgfmathresult
 \node at (\midangle:\innerpos) {#3};
 }
     \begin{table}[]
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
     \hline
          \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.2]

          \newcounter{a}
          \newcounter{b}
          \foreach \p/\t in {23/AbSn, 59/BrJH, 14/CoJN,
               4/DiH2}
             {
              \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
              \addtocounter{b}{\p}
              \slice{\thea/100*360}
              {\theb/100*360}
              {\p\%}{\t}
             }

         \end{tikzpicture}

         & 
         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.2]

         \newcounter{a}
         \newcounter{b}
         \foreach \p/\t in {56/AbSn, 2/BrJH, 31/CoJN,
               11/DiH2}
                {
                  \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
                  \addtocounter{b}{\p}
                  \slice{\thea/100*360}
                  {\theb/100*360}
                  {\p\%}{\t}
                 }

      \end{tikzpicture}

\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The quantity of given samples}
\label{
samples}

\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Enclose the `tikzpicture`s inside two tabulars, `tikzpicture`s normally build up on the baseline, whereas tables are naturally vertically centered around the baseline. Aside from this, counters `a` and `b` are defined twice.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{calc,array}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\slice}[4]{
\pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
\let\midangle\pgfmathresult
 % slice
 \draw[thick,fill=black!10] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;
 % outer label
 \node[label=\midangle:#4] at (\midangle:1) {};
 % inner label
 \pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
 \let\temp\pgfmathresult
 \pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}
 \let\innerpos\pgfmathresult
 \node at (\midangle:\innerpos) {#3};
 }
     \begin{table}
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
     \hline
     \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
          \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.2]
          \newcounter{a}
          \newcounter{b}
          \foreach \p/\t in {23/AbSn, 59/BrJH, 14/CoJN,
               4/DiH2}
             {
              \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
              \addtocounter{b}{\p}
              \slice{\thea/100*360}
              {\theb/100*360}
              {\p\%}{\t}
             }
         \end{tikzpicture}
         \end{tabular}
         & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}%
         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.2]
         \foreach \p/\t in {56/AbSn, 2/BrJH, 31/CoJN,
               11/DiH2}
                {
                  \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
                  \addtocounter{b}{\p}
                  \slice{\thea/100*360}
                  {\theb/100*360}
                  {\p\%}{\t}
                 }
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{tabular}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The quantity of given samples}
\label{samples}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that what I ask for actually. Any idea how to make the pie's with no colour?

Comment: @lol745: You mean the gray background? just remove the `fill=black!10` from your definition of `slice`. Aside note: also add an option `line join=round` to the `tikzpicture`s environment (`\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.2,line join=round]`) for better output.

Comment: Thanks, that what I am after, and many thanks for the [join=round], it solves another issue